# Is Jbehave / Cucumber is best to use for E-Commerce Project

Tags: selenium-webdriver, cucumber, jbehave

Hi I'm new to Jbehave and Cucumber. I need to use BDD framework to Automate the E-Commerce application. Please suggest which is good between two with Selenium.

Answer (score 1):

This is a matter of opinion. Try both and see which one you prefer.

Personally, I prefer Cucumber. But your opinion may be different.

Comment: Thank you for replying. sure, I will have a look into Cucumber.